# Mobile Chat functionality using Push Notifications, when should something be pushed?

Tags: android, iphone, blackberry, chat, push-notification

(The following question is for mobile platforms in general (iPhone, Android, Blackberry))

We are integrating chat functionality into our existing application. I designed the system with a .Net web service and Sql Database to keep track of chat messages. Everything's working fine so far, when the chat window is open.

I need a way to notify the user of a new message when he/she is not currently viewing the chat screen (meaning either the app is not in the foreground or they are in another section of the app (not the chat screen).

Obviously, push notifications would be perfect here, but I'm not sure when I should be sending pushes.

How would the client sending the message know whether or not the other guy is viewing the chat screen? Should I just be sending pushed with every single message and have the receiving device decide whether or not it needs to pop up a window or display something in a nofication bar?

It seems like overkill to be pushing every single time a message is sent. How is this normally done?

Any ideas at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The answer varies significantly depending on the platform - there is no one solution that covers android, iphone and blackberry, because they all have different constraints in the client code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First and foremost, keep in mind that your *server* will act as the broker for all messages passed between different chat clients. Here's how this could work:

- User `A` initiates a message for user `B`
- Message gets sent to the server.
- Server determines that this message is for user `B`.
- Server initiates a push notification and delivers the message to user `B`.

Now why would you need to push *every single* chat message? Because the only other way for your users to get notified would be to *poll* your server for new messages. Constant polling (at whatever rate you determine) is **extremely bad** in the mobile realm due to limited resources (battery, networking, etc.)

In a *push notification* scenario, it is up to your application to handle the logic of whether the user is *notified* on receiving a new message. What this means is that when user `B` receives a new message from user `A`, it's up to you to decide if you wish to notify `B` (i.e.  bring your app to the foreground) or not. In either scenario, you *want* to use push notifications instead of polling.

On a similar note, user `B` does not necessarily have to know that user `A`'s application (your app) is in the background which is why you will need to handle that logic (within your app) appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I take it that pushing is necessary every time a new message is available for a user, and the device should sort out how it's handled of course. That's all I needed to know, thanks.

Comment: @PaulG You're welcome! And just to clarify (for future readers), it's not _necessary_, but your users will appreciate it (in terms of battery life, etc.)

Comment: Pushing notification on every single message is not recommended IMHO. From Apple docs: "Sending notifications too frequently negatively impacts device battery life because a device must access the network to receive a notification."

Answer (score 0):

Push notification normally is applied to the application if it is not in the foreground. It is a way to wake-up the application to handle a new transaction from the server. Basically, a push notification is to be done if the client is running in the background and a new message is ready to be fetched from the server. As long as the new message is not fetched, if other messages arrive on the server, a push notification should be sent to the application.

Push notification is not necessary if the application is still running even if the user is viewing other screens of the application. It is however important that a thread is handling the connection to the server which is "patiently" waiting for transactions from the server.

One question, what protocol are you using for the messaging?.. Is it OMA IMPS protocol?